# Qthread emit only one signal in Golang

Tags: qt, go, qthread, qobject

I'm working on program with use Golang and Qt. I have a problem with Qthread for a heavy task.

This is my code:

**MainUi.go**

```
// Start new thread first
workThread := core.NewQThread(nil)
workThread.Start()

// Start a worker
wkr := worker.InitWorkPool()
wkr.MoveToThread(workThread)
wkr.ConnectReportOne(func(v0 int, v1 int) {

    // I put this code here to check is it called but not see anything
    fmt.Println("Report One") 

    label1.SetText(strconv.Itoa(v0))
    label2.SetText(strconv.Itoa(v1))
}
wkr.ConnectReportTwo(func(v0 int, v1 int, v2 int) {
    label3.SetText(strconv.Itoa(v0))
    label4.SetText(strconv.Itoa(v1))
    label5.SetText(strconv.Itoa(v2))

}
wkr.ConnectFinished(func() {
    widgets.QMessageBox_Information(nil, "Finished", "Task finished", widgets.QMessageBox__Ok, widgets.QMessageBox__Ok)
}
wkr.Run()
```

**Worker.go**

```
type WorkPool struct {
    core.QObject
    _ func(int, int) `signal:"reportOne"`
    _ func() `signal:"finished"`
    _ func(int, int, int) `signal:"reportTwo"`
}

func InitWorkPool() *WorkPool {
    return &WorkPool{}
}

func (wp *WorkPool) Run() {
    wp.ReportOne(11, 12) // This func not work
    wp.ReportTwo(21, 22, 23) // This func not work

    /* Do some stuff */

    wp.Finished() //This func work
}
```

I ran `qtmoc` to generation some addition code.

A function `wp.Finished()` work if I call it first or via another function like `StopTask()`. But `wp.ReportOne()` and `wp.ReportTwo()` not work and freeze `MainUi`.

Anyone can tell me what wrong in my code. It took me 2 days.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. This is my solution

```
func InitWorkPool() *WorkPool {
    wp := NewWorkPool() // Not return &WorkPool{}
    return wp
}
```

By the way, you use `go routines` as well to replace `Qthread` in Go.

Example source: https://github.com/therecipe/qt/issues/567#issuecomment-374654006